# Will keras.backend.function() with updates=None not update the state of a stateful model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have a stateful LSTM model. I need to call my own `K.function()` a few times myself for the same data so I can measure the uncertainty of the prediction. I have assumed the state of the model won't actually be updated since that would have been done with the update op Keras would normally pass to the `K.function(), updates = parameter`. Is that a correct assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, passing `updates=None` or `updates=[]` into `K.function` will evaluate only `outputs`. So you are fine as long as your `K.function()` argument doesn't make any changes itself.

This can be seen in the [tesorflow backend source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2284):
the call will evaluate just `self.outputs`, because `self.updates_op` is going to be an empty op.

I haven't worked with other backends, but I've looked into `cntk_backend.py` and `theano_backend.py` sources: they do the same.